# Diferença em formas de exclusão com EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quero saber, qual é a diferença(se existe) na forma de exclusão utlizando o EF

```
db.Contexto.Remove(objeto);
db.SaveChanges();
```

E utilizando o `EntityState.Deleted;`

```
Db.Entry(objeto).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
Db.SaveChanges();
```

Sei que com as duas formas é possível excluir. Elas tem a mesma função?

Posso usar qualquer uma a qualquer momento?

Tem algum caso especifico pra uso de alguma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sei que com as duas formas é possível excluir. Elas tem a mesma função?

Sim.

> Posso usar qualquer uma a qualquer momento?

Sim.

> Tem algum caso especifico pra uso de alguma?

[Remove()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove(v=vs.113).aspx) verifica algumas consistências a mais, como a própria materialização do conjunto (entidade principal e entidades agregadas) e o estado das propriedades, com a devida detecção dos campos que foram alterados, mas não há grande diferença entre eles. Em se tratando de exclusão, manter estado de alteração de campos não é lá tão importante.

Por verificar coisas a mais, `Remove()` é mais recomendado de ser usado. Por exemplo, se a operação envolve cascateamento de exclusão e a chave pode ser nula na entidade que não será excluída, usar `EntityState.Deleted` pode deixar o registro órfão, porque não há verificação completa da agregação, e sim, apenas do registro marcado para exclusão.